# NuGet and version control - how to handle Contents folder

Tags: version-control, nuget

With newer versions of NuGet it is no longer necessary to version control the `packages` folder and it is pretty simple to add that to the `.gitignore` file.

However, certain NuGet packages also add files to the `Contents` folder and the question is how to handle that? I *think* that that files should also be git-ignored but is it practical to maintain possibly complex Contents exclude rules?

Answer (score 3):

When you read the justification for "[Enabling Using NuGet Without Checking In Packages Folder](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Enabling%20Using%20NuGet%20Without%20Checking%20In%20Packages%20Folder)", it is about:

> This new feature will make it so that if the packages folder (or any package folder within the packages folder) is missing,  the packages folder (or missing package folder) will automatically be restored when compiling the application. This ensures that the application will compile even though the packages folder was missing at the time.

So basically what can be regenerated isn't versioned.
**The general idea is that, if it cannot be easily regenerated or fetched, it should be versioned**.

And it doesn't seem that what you put in `Content` is in that category, as illustrated by this example in the article "[Creating a NuGet Package in 7 easy steps - Plus using NuGet to integrate ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing Web Forms applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx) ";

> Step 2 - Add stuff to your `Content` Folder
>
> Since I want my NuGet package to add stuff to folders in my target Web Application, I put whatever I want in a folder called Content. Anything in that will show up in the root of my target project. This can be CSS, JS, CS or VB files, whatever. These files will all get dropped onto the project your package is applied to.

[image: Content folder]

So versioning said `Content` might be advisable.